# Using OleDB to read Spreadsheet created using Open XML 2.5 SDK

Tags: excel, openxml-sdk

I am creating a spreadsheet using Open XML 2.5 and reading it using OleDB. But opening the file with ACE throws errors when querying the schema.
I get "External table is not in the expected format."

Comment: It's easy to make an error when creating a spreadsheet with the OpenXML SDK. There are any number of things that could go wrong. Will the file open in Excel? What code are you using to create the file?